# When traveling in Southeast Asia, what is the best bank and card to use?

Tags: international, money-transfer, banking

I am going to travel to Asia, to Thailand and Indonesia among other countries (yet undecided). I am traveling from Denmark and have a Danish bank account - but also a Swedish one since I'm originally from Sweden. I am traveling with my girlfriend, and perhaps my brother, located in London.

**My question is which bank is best to use, and how do we best handle money transfers?** I know from experience that you lose a large percentage from international bank transfers, so I would like to avoid that.

**Does my nationality or the country I live in make a difference in the services I can use?**

Are there other services than banks that can lower the cost of having money on travel - like credit cards or newer transfer services?

**Edit** We will be traveling for at least two months.

Answer (score 3):

You havent indicated the duration of your visit.
The best way to do this is carry GBP. Exchange this into local currencies in the Thailand/Indonesia. Do not convert at Airport as the rates are bad. Go around shopping for rates. Most of the malls have tons of delears, bargain hard to get a good price.

For hotel stay, most of the hotels in Thailand/Indonesia charge you a USD rate for room. You can check with them, if so its better to get a Pre-paid USD card or even if you swipe your regular card, you would get a decent rate for USD-GBP.

The other option to make hotel payments is using Travellers cheques.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Dheer. I updated the question, mentioning that we will travel for at least 2 months, however no more than a month per country.